# Can't connect remotely using Remote-SSH: "spawn UNKNOWN"

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

I'm trying to remotely connect to a server (running on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS) through VSCode (started on WSL).

I've set the path to my WSL Config file (with the SSH keys inside) in VSCode Remote-SSH.

I can reach and connect to the server through the terminal as well as the VSCode terminal.

Yet, when trying to connect through Remote-SSH I'm getting the message

> Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: spawn UNKNOWN)

with the following error log:

```
[13:50:42.906] Log Level: 2
[13:50:42.922] remote-ssh@0.56.0
[13:50:42.922] win32 x64
[13:50:42.925] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+<net>.net", attempt 1
[13:50:42.925] SSH Resolver called for host: <net>.net
[13:50:42.926] Setting up SSH remote "<net>.net"
[13:50:42.970] Using commit id "<CommitID>" and quality "stable" for server
[13:50:42.974] Install and start server if needed
[13:50:44.876] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[13:50:44.888] Finding installed ssh failed: spawn UNKNOWN
[13:50:44.897] Resolver error: Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:394:11)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:549:9)
    at c:\Users\<user>\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0\out\extension.js:1:242426
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at q (c:\Users\<user>\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0\out\extension.js:1:242347)
    at k (c:\Users\<user>\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0\out\extension.js:1:242298)
    at _ (c:\Users\<user>\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0\out\extension.js:1:245580)
    at P (c:\Users\<user>\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0\out\extension.js:1:245741)
    at O (c:\Users\<user>\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0\out\extension.js:1:242117)
    at C (c:\Users\<user>\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0\out\extension.js:1:242026)
    at Object.t.generateMultiLineCommand (c:\Users\<user>\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0\out\extension.js:1:243396)
    at q (c:\Users\<user>\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0\out\extension.js:127:107623)
    at c:\Users\<user>\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0\out\extension.js:127:105016
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\<user>\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0\out\extension.js:127:110096)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\<user>\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0\out\extension.js:127:108158)
    at async c:\Users\<user>\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.56.0\out\extension.js:127:143767
[13:50:44.908] ------
```

Already tried setting up manually the vscode server remotely as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62443331)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem.

After trying everything, the only thing that worked 100% was just killing vs-code and opening it again.

Comment: I wasted so much time on this, and all I had to do was restart!

Answer (score 1):

Seems things got messed up with the update.
I fixed it by reinstalling the `Remote SSH extension: ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh` and reloading as you will be instructed to do.
I also just installed the entire `Remote Development extension: ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack` and reloaded vscode as instructed by vscode.

Before this though, I deleted (rm -rf) the contents of /home/<your_username>/.vscode-server/ bin/ and data/

Answer (score 0):

Before connecting by VSCode you need to make ssh connection from terminal to save remote host fingerprint to known_hosts file.

I didn't try but you may also add `StrictHostKeyChecking no` line into your ssh config file as below:

[Remote open ssh config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGntu.png)

[ssh config file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJNgS.png)

[without StrictHostKeyChecking line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYlpD.png)

[with StrictHostKeyChecking line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igud8.png)