# SSH via WSL in VSCODE to specific port

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, wsl-2, vscode-remote, vscode-remote-ssh

Referring to this thread [Can I ssh from WSL in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60150466/can-i-ssh-from-wsl-in-visual-studio-code)
I'm able to ssh on port 22 but is there a way to specify a port via WSL also?

my config:

```
Host IP
  HostName IP
  ForwardAgent yes
  Port 2222
```

my ssh.bat

```
C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe bash -ic 'ssh %*'
```

however it's not connecting with the following errors

```
[11:01:27.830] "install" terminal command done
[11:01:27.831] Install terminal quit with output: error: unknown command: bash
[11:01:27.832] Received install output: error: unknown command: bash
[11:01:27.833] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[11:01:27.834] Resolver error: Error:
```

I see the obvious command: bash error but I have multiple connections using this ssh.bat so reluctant to mess with it.

Any ideas would be helpful thanks!